# How to append the child at cursor position in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop, cursor

I am appending a child after drop in a container.But the data is  not getting appended at the cursor position.How do i do that in reactjs

```
 drop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample codesandbox code for Drag and drop implementation using React.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-sanderson-so76x

Hope this helps.